# Unexpected list append

Tags: python, list, append

```
import random
stats = []
statslist = []
rollslist = []
for var1 in range(4):
    stats.append(random.randrange(1, 7))
rollslist.append(stats)
print(stats)
b = min(stats)
stats.remove(b)
print(sum(stats))
statslist.append(sum(stats))
print(stats)
print(rollslist)
print(statslist)
```

actual result

```
[5, 1, 1, 3]
9
[5, 1, 3]
[[5, 1, 3]]
[9]
```

expected result

```
[5, 1, 1, 3]
9
[5, 1, 3]
[[5, 1, 1, 3]]
[9]
```

I'm expecting it to print four numbers for the fourth result instead of the three it's giving me. I appended the list before the number was removed. What am I missing?

Comment: it's all about reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You added a mutable list. When you modified it later, the modification affected the object you placed in the list, because it was a direct reference and not a copy.

The easiest way to make a copy of a list is to use slicing:

```
rollslist.append(stats[:])
```

Answer (score 3):

as Avinash mentioned, it's because you're still referring to the `stats` list. Meaning, changes made later (like the removal of an item) will still be reflected. For the expected behaviour, you can [make a copy of the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python) like so:

```
newCopy = list(stats)
rollslist.append(newCopy)
```